# Windows 10 automatic repair after swapping drives during hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, hibernate, file-corruption

I went to sleep and when I woke up. My PC looked off so I swapped Drive A for drive B and pressed the power button.

It went into automatic repair mode and won't get past it.

Turns out that drive A was not powered off, but instead in hibernation or sleep mode because that is the default settings on a fresh win 10 installation for some reason.

I tried chdsk through the command prompt and it said nothing wrong found, but unable to copy the log file.

Then tried sfc /scannow and it said it couldn't access it or something.

So I took drive B to another PC and hooked it up with an external SSD reader that works via USB.

When I go into the Users folder. It no longer has the username of that drive. Instead, it has the username from drive A like it was overwritten somehow.

When I try to access the folder, it says "you don't have permission to access this file".

I click ok and it says:

"To gain access to this folder, you must use the security tab".

So I go into the security tab and try to set "Everyone" as "Full Control".

It says "A error occurred while applying security information to

G:\users\test\documents

failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied."

I don't want to do a windows recovery while I can't ensure that the existing files will be transferred over.

How can I get my files out of this corrupted drive in order to do a fresh install?

Comment: Why don't you try to swap back? That would've been my first attempt, everything else can only make matters worse. BTW Your question is ambiguous - what is "swapped Drive A for drive B"? Were A and B both in the PC and did you swap physical places? Did you take out A and replace it with B - and was B empty?

Comment: I did try a swap back. Drive A was able to boot into the normal login screen. Drive B is the one that had its user folder replace with the one from drive A. When I say swap. I mean unplugged the power and sata from one drive and plugged in the other.

Comment: Delete the hiberfil.sys file from the drive.